# What are the physical properties of nitrosomethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've searched all over the web and I can't find any information about this compound. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitromethane

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because requests for specific data points do not belong on SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a rare one and quite unstable under standard conditions.

According to [Chemspider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.63264.html):

> Chemical formula: $\ce{CH3NO}$
>   Also known as  NITROSO-FORMAMIDE OXIME METHANE
>   It melts at $2.5~\mathrm{^\circ C}$ (measured) and has a density of $0.9~\pu{g cm^-3}$ (predicted).

According to [Paul D. Adeney, Willem J. Bouma, Leo Radom, William R. Rodwell. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1980,** *102* (12), 4069–4074](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00532a015):

> Nitrosomethane is known to be less stable than its isomer formaldoxime
>   and original attempts to isolate this molecule failed owing to it's
>   speedy isomerization to formaldoxime.